# Mongodb Can't start ubuntu 16.04 64bit

Tags: mongodb, openssl, ubuntu-16.04

```
mongod --version
mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by mongod) mongod: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: versionlibssl.so.10' not found (required by mongod)
```

and when i check the /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ folder these files already their can any one help me

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was running the command without referring the database location so this command

```
mongodb --dbpath /databaselocation
```

Comment: Please read this [how-to-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in case you haven't read.